# using raw_input to accept value for functions

Tags: python

I want the below program to accept input for a,b,c and d using raw_input.Please modify the below program to accept inputs for a,b,c and d.I tried doing this

```
def add(a, b)
    print "Enter the values of a and b"
    a = int(raw_input())
    b = int(raw_input())
    print return a + b
```

The trace back is

```
File "a.py", line 5
return a + b)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did this and I got syntax error.I did similarly for all the other functions.

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" %(a, b)
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    print "subtract %d - %d" %(a, b)
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    print "multiply %d * %d" %(a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b):
    print "divide %d + %d" %(a, b)
    return a / b

print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(30, 5)
height = subtract(78, 5)
weight = multiply(90, 2)
iq = divide(100, 2)

print "Age: %d, Height: %d, Weight: %d, IQ: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)

print "Here is a puzzle"

what = add(age, subtract(height, multiply(weight, divide(iq, 2))))

print "That is:", what, "How about that?"
```

Comment: Should I add my code in the comments here?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add more detail.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: What was the exact traceback of the error you got?

Comment: File "a.py", line 5
    return a + b)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That looks like you have a `)` to many on that line; it doesn't fit the code you posted in your question.

Comment: The error is the line `print return a + b` in your `add` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sys import argv
def add(a,b):
    print "Addition %d+%d" %(a,b)
    return a+b

a=int(raw_input())
b=int(raw_input())
#c=add(a,b)
#print "Addition Is %d" %c
print "Addition Is %d" %add(a,b)
```

try it for enter value through raw_input()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `add` function.

```
print return a + b
```

should be

```
return a + b
```